# Is there a simplification to the triple product of levi-civita symbols

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus

IS there any way to simplify:

$\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm}\epsilon_{mni}$

I know how to simplify the product of just two into summations of delta functions but not sure how to do it with three

Comment: Hint: there's a common index between the second and third Levi-Civita symbols. That means that you're able to combine one of the delta functions from the simplification of the first two with the third Levi-Civita symbol.

Comment: hm, im not sure how to do that simplification. I now have that $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm}\epsilon_{mni}= \delta_{il}\delta_{jm}\epsilon_{mni}-\delta_{im}\delta_{jl}\epsilon_{mni}$ but how do I combine the epsilons and the deltas?

Comment: $\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}\epsilon_{mni}$ is just $\epsilon_{jnl}$, etc. When you have $\delta_{ab}$ you can just eliminate it and set $a$ to $b$ or $b$ to $a$ in what’s left.

Comment: To understand why, think about something simple like $\delta_{ij}A_j$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression has three free indices — $j$, $l$, and $n$ — so it is a three-index tensor. It is built out of constant tensors, so it is a constant tensor. The only three-index constant tensor is the Levi-Civita tensor, so your expression *must* reduce to a scalar multiple of this tensor. The comments have already shown you how, using the identity for the contraction of two Levi- Civita tensors in terms of Kronecker deltas.